# Question on equivalent ways of describing homotopy extension property.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-extension-property

I am following a lecture note in algebraic topology. There I came across a property which is known as **Homotopy Extension Property** or in short **HEP.** The definition is given as follows $:$

**Definition** $:$ Let $X$ be a topological space and let $A$ be a subspace of $X.$ Then the pair $(X,A)$ is said to satisfy **HEP** if for a given map $f_0 : X \longrightarrow Y$ and a homotopy $g_t : A \longrightarrow Y$ of $f_0 \big\rvert_A$ there is an extension $h_t : X  \longrightarrow Y$ such that $h_t \big\rvert_A = g_t,$ for all $t \in I$ and $h_0 = f_0.$

It has been stated as an easy fact without proof that a pair $(X,A)$ has the homotopy extension property if and only if $(X \times \{0\}) \cup (A \times I)$ is a retract of $X \times I.$

But I don't get the point. Suppose that the pair $(X,A)$ has the  homotopy extension property then how does it imply that $X \times I$ retracts to $(X \times \{0\}) \cup (A \times I)\ $? Also how do I go the other way round? Would anybody please help me in this regard?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $A\subseteq X$ consider the map $f_0\colon X\ni x\longmapsto x\in X$ and the map $g_t\colon A\ni a\longmapsto a\in X$ for each $t\in I$. Note that $g_0=f_0\big|A$. So, if $(X,A)$ has homotopy extension property then we have a map $h_t\colon X\to X$  such that $h_0=f_0$ and $h_t\big|A=g_t$ for each $t\in I$. In other words, $h(x,0):=h_0(x)=f_0(x)=x$ for all $x\in X$ and $h(a,t):=h_t(a)=g_t(a)=a$ for all $(a,t)\in A\times I$. That is, $h\colon X\times I\to (X\times 0)\cup (A\times I)$ is our required retraction.

Conversely, let $r\colon X\times I\to (X\times 0)\cup (A\times I)$ be a retraction. Suppose, $Y$ is another topological space and we are given a map $f_0\colon X\to Y$ and a homotopy $g_t\colon A\to Y,\ t\in I$ such that $g_0(a)=f_0(a)$ for all $a\in A$. So, we have a well-defined map $\varphi\colon(X\times 0)\cup (A\times I)\to Y$ given by $$\varphi(z)=\begin{cases}f_0(x) &\text{ if }z=(x,0)\text{ for some }x\in X,\\ g(a,t) &\text{ if }z=(a,t)\text{ for some }(a,t)\in A\times I.\end{cases}$$ Note that $\varphi$ will be continuous if we assume $A\subseteq_\text{closed}X$. Then our required homotopy $h_t\colon X\to Y$ can be defined as $h_t(x):= \varphi\circ r(x,t)$ for $(x,t)\in X\times I$.

---

So, I have proved the equivalence under the assumption that $A$ is closed in $X$. But, this equivalence is still true without the closedness assumption, and the proof is quite long. For example, see $\text{Proposition A.18. on page 533}$ of [Hatcher's Algebraic Topology](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/AT/AT.pdf).

Comment: In the definition of homotopy extension property you have extended a homotopy from a restricted set to the entire space. Here you have taken only one map $\text {id} : \widehat {X} \longrightarrow  \widehat {X}.$ Do you take here the constant homotopy which doesn't change as $t$ varies from $0$ to $1\ $?

Comment: But then I think it extends to a homotopy $h_t : X \times I \longrightarrow \widehat X$ or in other words it extends to a map $h : (X \times I) \times I \longrightarrow \widehat X.$

Comment: Then the retraction may be given by $h \circ \iota,$ where $\iota : X \times I \longrightarrow (X \times I) \times I$ is the inclusion.

Comment: What is your $A\ $? When you make use of $\textbf {HEP}$ you need to specify a pair $(X,A)$ along with a map $f : X \longrightarrow Y$ and a homotopy $f_t : A \longrightarrow Y$ of $f \big\rvert_A.$ Right?

Comment: I don't get your point. Please see my above comment. I have some confusion here.

Comment: I mean how do you extend $\text {id}$ to $h$ by **HEP**?

Comment: I think you need to define $f_0 : X \longrightarrow X \times \{0\} \subseteq (X \times \{0\}) \cup (A \times I)$ by $x \longmapsto (x,0)$ and $g_t : A \longrightarrow A \times I \subseteq (X \times \{0\}) \cup (A \times I)$ defined by $a \longmapsto (a,t).$ Then only as a consequence of **HEP** it extends to a homotopy $h : X \times I \longrightarrow (X \times \{0\}) \cup (A \times I)$ which will work as a retraction $X \times I$ on $(X \times \{0\}) \cup (A \times I).$ But I appreciate your idea. That will make me comfortable in arguing this kind of problems. Thanks a lot.

Comment: For the reverse direction you used Pasting lemma. Right? In order to argue that $\varphi$ is continuous.

Comment: Another thing what I want to mention is that page no. $533$ is not there in Hatcher's book. I have a hardcopy of that book and what I can see is that $532$ is the last page marked in that book and after that there are few other pages for bibliography and index section.

Comment: (1) That is a notational problem, nothing more than that. Keep in mind, in your question codomain of every map are the same, and I followed while writing. (2) Yeah, pasting lemma. (3) That is why I added(in my answer) a link to Hatcher's book.  http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf  This link has more pages than a printed book.